# Maximum number of pixels in a Drawable image

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, drawable

Is there a maximum size for a Drawable jpg image in Android? Is perhaps  2M the maximum ?

I create a Drawable from a jpg file in the drawable folder this way:

Drawable image=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.file);

If number of pixels > 2M  then I get a runtime error:

06-16 17:01:17.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10830): java.lang.NullPointerException

If number of pixels < 2M then the code works perfectly

I compute the number of pixels as Xpixels times ypixels

Is that true? is 2M the maximum number of pixels allowed?
Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the size of the VM heap, and how much of it is available. It's usually 24MB, but I'm guessing creating a drawable involves decompressing the JPG into a much larger bitmap.